# How can I add an exception to the RKE2 default security policy to allow a single pod in a namespace to run as a root user

Tags: kubernetes, security, user-namespaces

Good afternoon.

So I have an RKE2 cluster with the security policy in place that does not allow root pods to run. I have a pod that has to run as root and have been trying to figure out how to allow my pod to deploy on this cluster without success.

So far I have tried to explicitly set the following:

```
securityContext:
  runAsUser: 0
  runAsGroup: 0
```

The pod still fails to be allowed to run on the environment. Is there a way to not totally disable the security policy and perhaps an an exception for a single namespace? Thank you.